# Disabling core dump for an already running process

Tags: linux, core-dump

We are dealing with a vendor's product, which has a nasty tendency to crash (with a massive core-dump) *on shut down* (upon receiving a `SIGTERM`).

We don't want to disable core-dumping for it completely, because, when crashes happen during normal runtime, cores are useful. Can we disable the core-dumping by a process right before killing it?

Other than by writing our own core-handling program, that is...

Comment: If the app was started via a systemd unit, you could try setting `KillSignal=SIGKILL` or some other signal in the unit (default is SIGTERM). This would then be used to stop the process. Or try adding a clean `ExecStop=` mechanism.

Comment: Yes, and we already asked the vendor if such a mechanism exists. Still, I wonder, if I can tell Linux, that a particular process' core shouldn't be dumped. _After_ the process was started already...

Answer (score 0):

One way I found -- surprisingly portable across different Unixes -- is to make the directory, where the core would be dumped (usually the process' current working directory), *unwritable*. For example, in this test the `sleep`-process will not produce a core-dump even upon segmentation-fault signal:

```bsh
sleep 50 &    # Launch sleep in the background
chmod u-w .   # Make the current directory unwritable for the owner
kill -11 $!   # Send the backgrounded sleep-process a SIGSEGV
chmod u+w .   # Restore the directory's permissions
```

This is good enough for our purposes -- when we're shutting the app down, we don't want new files written in the directory anyway (neither core-dumps, nor anything else) -- but it may not be suitable for all...

Wish something else -- even if Linux-specific -- existed.